# JSON cyclic object value when posting data in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I'm working with ChartJS to create charts with inputs from the user. It works fine showing the results for more than one dataset, but when I post the data with Javascript using JSON I get this error "cyclic object value". I've been not able to find an answer here, so I'm going to try to explain the issue the best I can.

This is the JS object (myChart.data.datasets) I'm posting, with two datasets from ChartJS:

[image]

Then I have a save() function which post that info (working fine for just one dataset) once the chart is done.

```
function save() {
    let data = {
          datasets: myChart.data.datasets
     };
     $.post('/save',
         {
             savedData: JSON.stringify(data),
             color: document.getElementById("color").value,
             ...
         }    
      )
}
```

I have no idea what's the cyclic object here, but I know **the problem is with the content of myChart.data.datasets being posted**. I've used some of the filters from other similar questions, but all them makes some of the data to be lost.

I use the same object to display the chart, which works perfectly with more than one dataset. The problem just happens when posting the data.

Any ideas about what it might be happening? Truly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: I think you might have extra braces.  

try:
function save() {
    let data = {
          datasets: myChart.data.datasets
     };
     $.post('/save', JSON.stringify(data))
}

Comment: @MattPengelly I have more variables apart from savedData, just added them to the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't trivial at all. As many questions & answers regarding cyclic objects in JSON are posted, none of them are very especific about what the solution is. For example, those which use the replacer parameter of JSON.stringify() don't work at all (at least in this case), as the data will be loss.

So, for me the solution was `dojox.json.href` from the Dojo javascript library. Here's [some documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/json/ref.html).

It's not the whole thing, but here's some code in case someone need it. First you serialize the object:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
    let data = { 
            datasets: dojox.json.ref.toJson(...) 
    }
    $.post('/save',
    ...
});
```

And then you deserialize it:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
      data = dojox.json.ref.fromJson(...);      
});
```

You can import the library just like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

This is the only way I've been capable to post the JSON object without loosing data.

Hope it helps!